# Xcode 4.3 ad hoc crashes iPad - runs in simulator, runs on iPad if loaded from Xcode

Tags: xcode4.3, ipad-2, adhoc, route-me

I am working in Xcode 4.3.1, and developing for iOS 5.1. My app runs fine in the simulator; it runs fine on my iPad if I install it from Xcode. But when I install it from an ad hoc archive, it crashes when I try to open a particular view controller. I have two ways to go to this view - one is through a tab bar, and the other is through a button on certain pages. The view controller is opening a map view, but this has worked fine in the past. I have made a change to my map source (it was previously opening an online source, now it's opening a local source), but the crash appears to be happening before this code is called, so I don't think that change is the problem. I have tried every suggestion I can find on Stack Overflow and elsewhere - mostly related to build settings or schemes - but haven't had any luck.

IF this is a code problem, then it is in the different library that I am calling (a route-me library) - but based on the crash log, I don't even think I'm getting that far, it seems to be a framework problem.

But if it's NOT the framework.....I have integrated MapView into my project, and based on Analyzer, this is the code I think I should be changed based on other questions and answers I've seen here:

```
- (id)initWithView: (UIView*) view
{   
    LogMethod();
    CLLocationCoordinate2D here;
    here.latitude = kDefaultInitialLatitude;
    here.longitude = kDefaultInitialLongitude;
    
    return [self initWithView:view
                   tilesource:[[RMOpenStreetMapSource alloc] init]
                 centerLatLon:here
                    zoomLevel:kDefaultInitialZoomLevel
                 maxZoomLevel:kDefaultMaximumZoomLevel
                 minZoomLevel:kDefaultMinimumZoomLevel
              backgroundImage:nil
                  screenScale:0];      
}
```

I think I need to rewrite the line that begins "return", but I can't figure out how to get it right. The samples I have found are much simpler than the above. The Xcode analyzer tells me:

1. Method returns on Objective-C object with a +1 retain count
2. Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1

I am an experienced Windows programmer - but I am new to Apple and Xcode.

Here is the symbolicated crash report:

> ```
> base address 0 Incident Identifier:
> 1805810C-950E-41CE-9773-97C1798A3007 CrashReporter Key:  
> 13ee73abe8e268a2ab7a84b973bc08df600dd98b Hardware Model:      iPad2,1
> Process:         Waggoner [963] Path:           
> /var/mobile/Applications/AF402A1F-F483-4517-9482-177C928D3859/Waggoner.app/Waggoner
> Identifier:      Waggoner Version:         ??? (???) Code Type:      
> ARM (Native) Parent Process:  launchd [1]
>
> Date/Time:       2012-04-12 21:08:25.611 -0700 OS Version:      iPhone
> OS 5.1 (9B176) Report Version:  104
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes: 0x00000000,
> 0x00000000 Crashed Thread:  0
>
> Last Exception Backtrace: 0   CoreFoundation               
>   0x33e5088f __exceptionPreprocess + 163 1   libobjc.A.dylib           
>   0x32942259 objc_exception_throw + 33 2   CoreFoundation              
>   0x33e5392f +[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 175 3  
> CoreFoundation                    0x33e52915 ___forwarding___ + 301 4  
> CoreFoundation                    0x33dad650 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48 5
> Waggoner                          0x0003d0a5 0x26000 + 94373 6   Waggoner
>   0x0006241f 0x26000 + 246815 7   Waggoner                     
>   0x0005aeb3 0x26000 + 216755 8   Waggoner                     
>   0x0005bca5 0x26000 + 220325 9   Waggoner                     
>   0x0005c3cd 0x26000 + 222157 10  Waggoner                     
>   0x0005c055 0x26000 + 221269 11  Waggoner                     
>   0x00061693 0x26000 + 243347 12  Waggoner                     
>   0x000600c5 0x26000 + 237765 13  Waggoner                     
>   0x0002827f 0x26000 + 8831 14  UIKit                        
>   0x35aa6e33 -[UIViewController view] + 167 15  UIKit                  
>   0x35b067e5 -[UITabBarController
> transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:]
> + 93 16  UIKit                            0x35b06783 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 31 17  UIKit                          0x35b060bd -[UITabBarController
> _setSelectedViewController:] + 301 18  UIKit                          0x35b05df1 -[UITabBarController setSelectedIndex:] + 241 19  Waggoner
>   0x00036a53 0x26000 + 68179 20  CoreFoundation               
>   0x33daa3fd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 53 21
> UIKit                             0x35a88faf -[UIApplication
> sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 63 22  UIKit                        
>   0x35a88f6b -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:]
> + 31 23  UIKit                            0x35a88f49 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 45 24  UIKit                        
>   0x35a88cb9 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] +
> 493 25  UIKit                             0x35a895f1 -[UIControl
> touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 477 26  UIKit                        
>   0x35a87ad3 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 319 27  UIKit         
>   0x35a874c1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 381 28  UIKit                    
>   0x35a6d83d -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 357 29  UIKit               
>   0x35a6d0e3 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5827 30  GraphicsServices     
>   0x3332522b PurpleEventCallback + 883 31  CoreFoundation              
>   0x33e24523 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
> + 39 32  CoreFoundation                   0x33e244c5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 141 33  CoreFoundation                    0x33e23313 __CFRunLoopRun + 1371 34  CoreFoundation               
>   0x33da64a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301 35  CoreFoundation             
>   0x33da636d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105 36  GraphicsServices             
>   0x33324439 GSEventRunModal + 137 37  UIKit                        
>   0x35a9be7d UIApplicationMain + 1081 38  Waggoner                     
>   0x00027c9f 0x26000 + 7327 39  Waggoner                     
>   0x00027c80 0x26000 + 7296
>
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0
> Crashed: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x370ec32c __pthread_kill
> + 8 1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x33252208 pthread_kill + 48 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x3324b298 abort + 88 3  
> libc++abi.dylib                   0x30943f64 abort_message + 40 4  
> libc++abi.dylib                   0x30941346 _ZL17default_terminatev + 18
> 5   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x32942350 _objc_terminate + 140 6 
> libc++abi.dylib                   0x309413be
> _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 70 7   libc++abi.dylib                0x3094144a std::terminate() + 14 8   libc++abi.dylib              
>   0x3094281e __cxa_rethrow + 82 9   libobjc.A.dylib              
>   0x329422a2 objc_exception_rethrow + 6 10  CoreFoundation             
>   0x33da6506 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398 11  CoreFoundation             
>   0x33da6366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98 12  GraphicsServices             
>   0x33324432 GSEventRunModal + 130 13  UIKit                        
>   0x35a9be76 UIApplicationMain + 1074 14  Waggoner                     
>   0x00027c98 0x26000 + 7320 15  Waggoner                     
>   0x00027c78 0x26000 + 7288
>
> Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager Thread
> 1: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x370dc3a8 kevent + 24 1  
> libdispatch.dylib                 0x324a0f04 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708 2
> libdispatch.dylib                 0x324a0c22 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30
>
> Thread 2 name:  WebThread Thread 2: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib       
>   0x370dc004 mach_msg_trap + 20 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib       
>   0x370dc1fa mach_msg + 50 2   CoreFoundation               
>   0x33e243ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120 3   CoreFoundation       
>   0x33e23124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876 4   CoreFoundation               
>   0x33da649e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294 5   CoreFoundation             
>   0x33da6366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98 6   WebCore                      
>   0x376180f0 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396 7   libsystem_c.dylib           
>   0x3321372e _pthread_start + 314 8   libsystem_c.dylib            
>   0x332135e8 thread_start + 0
>
> Thread 3: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370eccd4
> __workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x3320df36 _pthread_wqthread + 610 2   libsystem_c.dylib                0x3320dcc8 start_wqthread + 0
>
> Thread 4: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370eccd4
> __workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x3320df36 _pthread_wqthread + 610 2   libsystem_c.dylib                0x3320dcc8 start_wqthread + 0
>
> Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.locationd.registration.xpcq
> Thread 5: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370dc06c
> semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8 1   libdispatch.dylib            
>   0x324a1182 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 122 2   libdispatch.dylib 
>   0x324a11f4 dispatch_semaphore_wait$VARIANT$mp + 32 3   CoreLocation  
>   0x33351db0 CLClientInvokeCallback(__CLClient*, CLClientEvent,
> __CFDictionary const*) + 340 4   CoreLocation                     0x33354530 ___CLClientCreateConnection_block_invoke_0 + 320 5  
> CoreLocation                      0x33387eea
> __setDefaultMessageHandler_onQueue_block_invoke_0 + 46 6   CoreLocation                   0x333856ca
> CLConnection::handleMessage(CLConnectionMessage*) + 42 7  
> CoreLocation                      0x333864d8
> __setEventHandler_block_invoke_0 + 360 8   libxpc.dylib                   0x338b58c2 __XPC_CONNECTION_EVENT_HANDLER_CALLOUT__ + 30 9  
> libxpc.dylib                      0x338aed5c _xpc_connection_recv_message
> + 500 10  libxpc.dylib                    0x338aeb18 _xpc_connection_wakeup_recv + 160 11  libxpc.dylib                   0x338ae9b8 _xpc_connection_wakeup2 + 1264 12  libxpc.dylib           
>   0x338ae3f6 _xpc_connection_wakeup + 62 13  libdispatch.dylib         
>   0x324a22da _dispatch_source_invoke + 510 14  libdispatch.dylib       
>   0x3249fb7a _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 46 15 
> libdispatch.dylib                 0x3249fc9e _dispatch_queue_drain + 162
> 16  libdispatch.dylib                 0x3249fb6e
> _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 34 17  libdispatch.dylib              0x3249fc9e _dispatch_queue_drain + 162 18  libdispatch.dylib         
>   0x3249fb6e _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 34 19 
> libdispatch.dylib                 0x3249fc9e _dispatch_queue_drain + 162
> 20  libdispatch.dylib                 0x3249fb6e
> _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 34 21  libdispatch.dylib              0x324a07e0 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 204 22  libsystem_c.dylib      
>   0x3320ddf4 _pthread_wqthread + 288 23  libsystem_c.dylib            
>   0x3320dcc8 start_wqthread + 0
>
> Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader Thread 6: 0  
> libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x370dc004 mach_msg_trap + 20 1  
> libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x370dc1fa mach_msg + 50 2  
> CoreFoundation                    0x33e243ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort +
> 120 3   CoreFoundation                    0x33e23124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
> 4   CoreFoundation                    0x33da649e CFRunLoopRunSpecific +
> 294 5   CoreFoundation                    0x33da6366 CFRunLoopRunInMode +
> 98 6   Foundation                     0x32d3dbb2
> +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 302 7   Foundation                        0x32d3da7a -[NSThread main] + 66 8   Foundation                   
>   0x32dd158a __NSThread__main__ + 1042 9   libsystem_c.dylib           
>   0x3321372e _pthread_start + 314 10  libsystem_c.dylib            
>   0x332135e8 thread_start + 0
>
> Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
>     r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
>     r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3efcfd98      r6: 0x00000002      r7: 0x2fe24a78
>     r8: 0x00153670    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x000ad13c
>     ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fe24a6c      lr: 0x3325220f      pc: 0x370ec32c   cpsr: 0x000f0010
>
> Binary Images:    0x26000 -    0x9afff +Waggoner armv7 
> <685c2b1700e8372e9c25bfde5c69628e>
> /var/mobile/Applications/AF402A1F-F483-4517-9482-177C928D3859/Waggoner.app/Waggoner
> 0x2fe25000 - 0x2fe46fff  dyld armv7 
> <4a817f3e0def30d5ae2032157d889c1d> /usr/lib/dyld 0x306b4000 -
> 0x306c0fff  CoreVideo armv7  <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo 0x30817000 -
> 0x3085cfff  GeoServices armv7  <a26be2e76e8730ab91a16502aba376be>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
> 0x3086b000 - 0x3093bfff  WebKit armv7 
> <6ff2796c2f933050ac6ecdee9fc6a216>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit 0x3093c000 -
> 0x3093cfff  vecLib armv7  <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
> 0x3093d000 - 0x30944fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7 
> <bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib 0x30961000
> - 0x30967fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
> 0x30968000 - 0x3097bfff  DataDetectorsCore armv7 
> <3f4596cbe1b13fdcb427d87de21df3f6>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
> 0x3097c000 - 0x30adbfff  libmecabra.dylib armv7 
> <06a0a1ee488030169bdfab11fc8d2c5c> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
> 0x30b8a000 - 0x30b8efff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7 
> <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
> 0x30c5d000 - 0x30c73fff  libmis.dylib armv7 
> <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib 0x30c74000 -
> 0x30d1efff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
> 0x30d8d000 - 0x30d8efff  CoreSurface armv7 
> <7850befd26b630f183ee326aaadd7b34>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
> 0x30d8f000 - 0x30da1fff  DataDetectorsUI armv7 
> <50ea319aaeb7307e92719980dd4b2953>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
> 0x30da3000 - 0x30de7fff  MobileCoreServices armv7 
> <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
> 0x30e1f000 - 0x30e3cfff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7 
> <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib 0x30f23000 - 0x30f2ffff 
> libz.1.dylib armv7  <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b>
> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib 0x313bf000 - 0x313cefff  SpringBoardServices
> armv7  <ca5b10014b473d2eaec5c48d89ee1b54>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
> 0x314f5000 - 0x314f6fff  libdyld.dylib armv7 
> <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
> 0x31500000 - 0x31523fff  Bom armv7  <c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom 0x31621000 -
> 0x31645fff  PrintKit armv7  <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
> 0x3164b000 - 0x31689fff  IOKit armv7 
> <fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit 0x3168c000
> - 0x316b1fff  OpenCL armv7  <ec915bfc3f7633dda61b5fc87459119b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL 0x31b5d000 -
> 0x31baefff  CoreText armv7  <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText 0x31baf000 -
> 0x31bbafff  AccountSettings armv7  <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
> 0x31bf9000 - 0x31bfdfff  IOSurface armv7 
> <6ae77a40f8e93f28bc466ca93f5675d4>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
> 0x31c4b000 - 0x31c5ffff  PersistentConnection armv7 
> <65682d21486836a3aa3e17b9461e7b3a>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
> 0x31c60000 - 0x31cb8fff  CoreAudio armv7 
> <be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio 0x31d0e000 -
> 0x31d56fff  CoreMedia armv7  <eb1f503312be3c93b07b2d0d25177000>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia 0x31e9d000 -
> 0x31fc2fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
> 0x31fc3000 - 0x31ff8fff  SystemConfiguration armv7 
> <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
> 0x31ffe000 - 0x32041fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7 
> <95b49daf4cf038b6bea8010bba3a1e26>
> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib 0x32042000 - 0x32044fff 
> MobileInstallation armv7  <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
> 0x32081000 - 0x320c1fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7 
> <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
> 0x320c2000 - 0x321b0fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7 
> <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
> 0x321b1000 - 0x321ecfff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7 
> <55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
> 0x321ed000 - 0x321f9fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7 
> <bdb2b4d1a78c39c1ba60d791207aed2a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
> 0x32243000 - 0x32258fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7 
> <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
> 0x3249d000 - 0x324b3fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7 
> <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
> 0x32646000 - 0x32647fff  DataMigration armv7 
> <d77f0e8f39ee37f5a2ac713a3fd9e693>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
> 0x32648000 - 0x3267ffff  Security armv7 
> <eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security 0x326e0000 -
> 0x326e6fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
> 0x32740000 - 0x32742fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7 
> <d4d4aa3090c83e87bcb15ed00b93fd5c>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
> 0x32743000 - 0x32743fff  Accelerate armv7 
> <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate 0x32744000
> - 0x32835fff  QuartzCore armv7  <a2afbe6483683d05ad51b106f98776e2> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore 0x328e4000
> - 0x328eafff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
> 0x32939000 - 0x329fffff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7 
> <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib 0x32c61000
> - 0x32c61fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <a80aaa9989483ce3a496a061fd1e9e0a>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
> 0x32c62000 - 0x32cdbfff  ProofReader armv7 
> <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
> 0x32d2d000 - 0x32eabfff  Foundation armv7 
> <c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation 0x3301e000
> - 0x33021fff  NetworkStatistics armv7  <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
> 0x33022000 - 0x33023fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7 
> <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib 0x33025000 - 0x3305dfff 
> VideoToolbox armv7  <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
> 0x330a4000 - 0x330eefff  ManagedConfiguration armv7 
> <5e0a131bbfec305ea01f9e01f486da63>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
> 0x330ef000 - 0x330f3fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7 
> <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
> 0x33140000 - 0x33143fff  libmacho.dylib armv7 
> <e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
> 0x331d7000 - 0x331e4fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7 
> <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib 0x33205000
> - 0x33291fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
> 0x33297000 - 0x3329afff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7 
> <b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187>
> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib 0x3329b000 - 0x332b4fff 
> libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <1828cddc5dd93c61afbefb59587d7f8a>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
> 0x332c0000 - 0x3330cfff  CoreTelephony armv7 
> <e8eb52ca5fe33c7488a33efd222e7804>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
> 0x33320000 - 0x3332afff  GraphicsServices armv7 
> <e21a6e61bdd136b6805a9e3abe2e3d1f>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
> 0x3332b000 - 0x33330fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7 
> <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib 0x33331000 - 0x33340fff 
> GenerationalStorage armv7  <d84c3fd0e7bd36e78c256f2f4c5a4e91>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
> 0x3334f000 - 0x3339dfff  CoreLocation armv7 
> <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
> 0x333b7000 - 0x33496fff  RawCamera armv7 
> <98fb7b5042b2314b86f4be8d2881bd04>
> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera 0x334a1000 -
> 0x334e0fff  QuickLook armv7  <802b1092542a3017a0380632502610d4>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook 0x33759000 -
> 0x3375dfff  AggregateDictionary armv7 
> <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
> 0x33762000 - 0x33782fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7 
> <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib 0x338ad000
> - 0x338befff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib 0x338bf000 - 0x338c6fff 
> AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <0703f561f9a038b6850d6e93bba7e5f4>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
> 0x3399f000 - 0x33a1efff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7 
> <bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
> 0x33a4a000 - 0x33a50fff  libnotify.dylib armv7 
> <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
> 0x33b72000 - 0x33b88fff  DictionaryServices armv7 
> <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
> 0x33b89000 - 0x33b89fff  liblangid.dylib armv7 
> <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib 0x33b91000
> - 0x33bcdfff  AppSupport armv7  <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
> 0x33d90000 - 0x33d93fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7 
> <f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
> 0x33d97000 - 0x33eaefff  CoreFoundation armv7 
> <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
> 0x33ebf000 - 0x33ec0fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7 
> <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
> 0x33fa1000 - 0x34262fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7 
> <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
> 0x3427a000 - 0x3427efff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7 
> <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
> 0x3427f000 - 0x34289fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7 
> <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
> 0x3428a000 - 0x3428afff  libunwind.dylib armv7 
> <e0a73a57795f3e1698a52ebe6fc07005> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
> 0x3428b000 - 0x342aafff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7 
> <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
> 0x342c1000 - 0x34398fff  CFNetwork armv7 
> <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork 0x343ea000 -
> 0x343f4fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1>
> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib 0x34485000 - 0x344d6fff  libstdc++.6.dylib
> armv7  <c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
> 0x34a6e000 - 0x34a6ffff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7 
> <66e985f3eea03ef08afb7cf4c153f76e>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib 0x34a70000 - 0x34a74fff 
> libcache.dylib armv7  <d6a7436ed8dc33d795c9b42baf864882>
> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib 0x34b0b000 - 0x34b7bfff  CoreImage
> armv7  <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage 0x34cee000 -
> 0x34e94fff  CoreData armv7  <b0215b6d4d143859a2b313ecade095ec>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData 0x3508a000 -
> 0x350d3fff  AddressBook armv7  <b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
> 0x351ed000 - 0x351f6fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7 
> <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
> 0x35238000 - 0x352e5fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7 
> <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib 0x35439000
> - 0x3543ffff  MobileIcons armv7  <ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
> 0x35a20000 - 0x35a69fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7 
> <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib 0x35a6a000
> - 0x35f0cfff  UIKit armv7  <d72bcc68e76a3a55a963590cdcffe8cd> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit 0x35f39000 -
> 0x35f41fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
> 0x35f94000 - 0x35f94fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7 
> <ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
> 0x35f95000 - 0x360dafff  CoreGraphics armv7 
> <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
> 0x362a4000 - 0x362b3fff  OpenGLES armv7 
> <e80acc691001301e96101bb89d940033>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES 0x36398000 -
> 0x368dcfff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
> 0x368e4000 - 0x36ac8fff  AudioToolbox armv7 
> <c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
> 0x36c43000 - 0x36fb2fff  TextInput armv7 
> <8d7f24642c7634cc8e3a6e65f1dcd98e>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
> 0x36fb3000 - 0x36fb3fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7 
> <eb82984fa36c329387aa518aa5205f3d> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
> 0x36fb4000 - 0x36fc5fff  DataAccessExpress armv7 
> <e6144ba265da3bb7b9a263aa1a29b054>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
> 0x36fd2000 - 0x36fd5fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7 
> <356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib 0x36fd6000 - 0x37020fff 
> libvDSP.dylib armv7  <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
> 0x37021000 - 0x37029fff  MobileWiFi armv7 
> <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
> 0x37043000 - 0x37048fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7 
> <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
> 0x370db000 - 0x370f1fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7 
> <7ac5560851ce3cb3981068092074b409>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x370f2000 - 0x372affff 
> ImageIO armv7  <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO 0x3731a000 -
> 0x3731bfff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498>
> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib 0x373a4000 - 0x373bafff  EAP8021X
> armv7  <fffe86a22bc434a6ae84f23bfecef9d6>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
> 0x373bb000 - 0x37504fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7 
> <b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
> 0x3756f000 - 0x37d2dfff  WebCore armv7 
> <814351ff217e3425a8e532c2e2251f73>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore 0x37eac000
> - 0x37eaffff  CoreTime armv7  <a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
> 0x38178000 - 0x38250fff  vImage armv7 
> <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
> ```

Comment: Please symbolicate the crash report.

Comment: @jrtc27 Here is the symbolicated crash report.  </br>

Comment: `0x0005aeb3 0x26000 + 216755 8 Waggoner
0x0005bca5 0x26000 + 220325 9 Waggoner
0x0005c3cd 0x26000 + 222157 10 Waggoner
0x0005c055 0x26000 + 221269 11 Waggoner
0x00061693 0x26000 + 243347 12 Waggoner
0x000600c5 0x26000 + 237765 13 Waggoner` is not symbolicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly common route-me problem; I just ran up against it again, and wasted more time on it, like you did.

You need to add this piece of code. I put it in initWithNibName in the view controller containing the MapView.

```
    //let the linker know that you access RMMapView
    [RMMapView class];
```

The point seems to be that the linker doesn't know you need most of the route-me code if you create your map view with IB, and for the release build the code that it thinks is unused gets aggressively pruned out of the linked libraries.

http://groups.google.com/group/route-me-map/browse_thread/thread/ad841852d30d2732/75e9af55134e6978?lnk=gst&q=doesNotRecognizeSelector#75e9af55134e6978

Comment: thanks for the reply, and sorry for the slow response.  This has been helpful, including the link to the route-me google group.  But I'm not quite there, because I now have a different problem that I haven't been able to find an answer to in the group.  I will post that to a new question.